# Unable to parse JSON, uncaught syntax error?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse the following JSON:

```
06-22 18:49:17.182: ERROR/HTMLContacts(2716): Json:
[{"contactId":"1","contactPhoto":"SIkADAjz94lQTkcNChoKAAAADUlIRFIAAABgAAAAYAgCAAAAbfrgbwAAAANzQklUBQYFMwuNgAAA\nHuhJREFUeJztfU2LJLuS5ZlGAcfAEyTIggy4D14uZjGznB87q9nO75nFwMyiG+rBuxAJN0GCdLAD\nocUsTHL3yMisj3vvm6abFkVVVoRcLpns85hJ+Z/+53//Hw4g4djUoS50oEsdANwF+PnLmaQ60IEE... }
```

It is a huge string array with an array length of almost 10,000.

I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL -- From line 1 of file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

Could someone explain what is happening?

Comment: have to tried to validate the json string? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks , yes there is an issue and i am tring to figure out "contactPhoto": "SIkADAjz94lQTkcNCho
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Comment: Well, http://jsonlint.com/ tells you where and what the error is. You should fix it. As we have no access to the whole data, we cannot help you more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't make any sense of that at all.  Have you tried validating your JSON first though?
http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I tried validating the json .This is the error message "contactPhoto": "SIkADAjz94lQTkcNCho
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['  ..any help ? i am not able to get it

Comment: so are you missing a closing quote then?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my phoneGap app running on MC40 android 2.3 and all I had to do is replace `JSON.parse with $.parseJSON` .Apparently JSON.parse has compatibility issues with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Unescaped character that JavaScript isn't liking. Make sure it can take any character you receive.

Comment: Java?  you mean _javascript_?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no tabs in there by replacing them with `\t`.